# recursive elementwise addition of nested array to get a scalar value

Tags: python

I want to write a function that receives an array, checks if received array is a nested array (can be deeply nested) and sums the elements in nested array and then add elements in resulting array until I get a scalar value

```
data_array 
[[[9.2e-05 9.4e-05 9.3e-05]
  [9.3e-05 9.9e-05 9.6e-05]
  [9.3e-05 9.8e-05 9.2e-05]]

 [[9.03e-05 8.9e-05 9.03e-05]
  [8.43e-05 8.9e-05 9.01e-05]
  [7.95e-05 7.7e-05 7.21e-05]]]
Desired_output = [[9.27e-05 9.7e-05 9.36e-05] [8.43e-05 8.56e-05 8.4e-05]] -> [0.000094 0.000084] -> 0.000089
```

(first the elements are averaged column first and then added rowwise until scalar value is achieved)

```
1st example has 2 lists of two 2d (dim 3*3) arrays. I want to get average for each element column wise and and get 2 (1*3) arrays, then I get 1 (1*3) array which is average of two 2d (1*3) arrays. Finally with the last 1*3 array I want to sum all the elements and get the scalar value
```

or

```
data_array
[[[[8.4e-05 8.5e-05 9.5e-05]
   [8.7e-05 8.8e-05 8.8e-05]
   [7.6e-05 6.8e-05 6.3e-05]]

  [[8.8e-05 9.4e-05 8.8e-05]
   [8.4e-05 8.9e-05 9.3e-05]
   [8.1e-05 8.1e-05 7.7e-05]]]]
Desired_output = [[0.000083 8.03e-05 8.2e-05] [8.43e-05 8.8e-05 8.6e-05]] -> [8.17e-05 8.61e-05] -> 8.38e-05
```

(first the elements are averaged column first and then added rowwise until scalar value is achieved)

or

```
data_array
[[[[4.77e-05]]]
 [[[3.75e-05]]]
 [[[2.95e-05]]]]
```

Desired Output -> 3.76e-05

**My raw attempt**

```
import numpy as np    
def sumOfArray(array):
    sumTotal = []
    for element in array:
        if type(element) is list:
            sumTotal += np.sum(list, axis=1)
            sumTotal += sumOfArray(list)
        else:
            return array
    return [sum(elem) for elem in sumTotal]
```

Comment: You know you can just call `np.sum(data_array)` and it will do exactly what you describe?

Comment: @CoryKramer I am getting data in nested arrays and I need the scalar value irrespective how nested the array becomes.

Comment: I don't understand how you get your first output

Comment: If those are really arrays, they are multidimensional arrays, not nested lists

Comment: Is there's something wrong with your attempt, please describe it as explained in [ask] and [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

A good application for recursion!

See the following code to do what you want (and raise exceptions if the data is bad). There is no strict need for `numpy` if you want to avoid it:

```
def nested_array_to_scalar(data):
    total = 0.0
    for datum in data:
        if isinstance(datum, (int, float)):
            total += datum
        elif isinstance(datum, (list, tuple)):                     
            total += nested_array_to_scalar(datum)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Data must be lists or numbers in all dimensions!")
    return total
```

EDIT: You do know a lot of the sums in your exemplar test cases are wrong?

```
>>> 4.77e-5 + 3.75e-5 + 2.95e-5
0.0001147 # = 1.147e-4
```

EDIT 2: If you DO want to use `numpy`, make sure to add the `numpy` data types to the `isintance` args. e.g.

```
isinstance(datum, (list, tuple))
```

to

```
isinstance(datum, (list, tuple, np.array))
```

Comment: I have taken average instead of sum

Comment: That is a very different problem to the one you asked! Your request doesn't mention averaging anywhere

Comment: Is summing what you want? Or do you want averaging?

Comment: first average in numpy array with axis = 1 and in last array sum all elements

Comment: So for an array of N dimensions you want to average the Nth dimension, then the N-1th, N-2th, ..., 2nd then sum the first dimension?

Comment: Or do you want to flatten all dimensions higher than 2 so that your array is always 2D then average the 2nd dimension and sum the 1st?

Comment: take average column wise in all arrays and then sum the last dimension of array to get a scalar value

Comment: What dimensions of input data are you constrained by? Will the atomic units of the nest always be 2D arrays? Please could you provide some more context?

Comment: yes  atomic units of the nest always be 2D arrays

Comment: So you have a list of 2D arrays? Or can it be a list of lists of 2D arrays?

Comment: it can be a  list of lists of 2D arrays

Comment: This is very poorly defined. What if I have a mixed list of 2D arrays and lists of 2D arrays? Is that allowed?

Comment: float32 values in list of 2D arrays (I have given 3 examples)

Comment: I can see your examples but none of them seem to do what you describe. They all appear to be a simple recursive average.

Comment: 1st example has 2 lists of two 2d (dim 3*3) arrays. I want to get average for each element column wise and and get 2 (1*3) arrays, then I get 1 (1*3) array which is average of two 2d (1*3) arrays. Finally with the last 1*3 array I want to sum all the elements and get the scalar value